# Pass different connection strings to IDesignTimeDbContextFactory using Azure Functions with .NET 5 (Isolated)

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, azure-functions, .net-5

I have created a new FunctionApp in Visual Studio Version 16.10.0 using the template Azure Functions with .NET 5 (Isolated) and Http trigger.

Following the guide for Design-time DbContext Creation it seems I can only use `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` and not `application services`. I have created a separate question for using `HostBuilder`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=vs

[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools - Azure Functions with .NET 5 (Isolated) Design-time DbContext Creation with HostBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67834480/3850405)

Getting the connection string from `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` is not a problem at runtime:

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {

        var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FunctionApp1.Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

Function1cs:

```
var applicationDbContextFactory = new ApplicationDbContextFactory();
using var context = applicationDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(null);
```

[image]

However using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` `Add-Migration InitialCreate` in `Package Manager Console` I get the following error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation.  ---> System.ArgumentNullException:
> Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

This is expected since environment variables are not present when running via `Package Manager Console`. I can not use code like this either:

```
$ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection="Server=tcp:mySqlServerStuffxxx"
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

Will result in the following error:

> The property 'DefaultConnection' cannot be found on this object.
> Verify that the property exists and can be set.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67822243/3850405

I can load a connection string like this but in production I would like a different value. Works a lot better with `appsettings.json` that gets deployed and checked in by default.

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
    .Build();

var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418717/3850405

I then tried to use `-Args` as mentioned in MS Docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=vs#args

```
var connectionString = args[0];
```

With this I could add a new migration and it looked good.

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Args 'Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FunctionApp1.Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true'
```

However when running `Update-Database` it fails with the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 50 - Local
> Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is
> invalid.

```
Update-Database -Args 'Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FunctionApp1.Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true'
```

If I either hard code the exact same value or get the value from `ConfigurationBuilder` everything works with these settings.

```
var connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FunctionApp1.Test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
```

[image]

Which is the best way to pass different connection strings to `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` that works both at runtime and `Package Manager Console`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the solution with `ConfigurationBuilder` works without duplicating the connection string we decided to use that solution and then only use `ApplicationDbContextFactory` for design and never in code.

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
            .Build();

        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Then got another error when Entity Framework was moved to its own class library.

> Your target project 'FunctionApp1.FunctionApp' doesn't match your
> migrations assembly 'FunctionApp1.EntityFramework'. Either change your
> target project or change your migrations assembly. Change your
> migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g.
> options.UseSqlServer(connection, b =>
> b.MigrationsAssembly("FunctionApp1.FunctionApp")). By default, the
> migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext. Change
> your target project to the migrations project by using the Package
> Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing
> "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations project.

Solved this by setting Default Project in PMC as the Entity Framework project and Startup project as the project containing `local.settings.json`.